# NiFi connection to Hive fails

Tags: hive, apache-nifi

I am trying to insert into Hive version 2.3.2 using NiFi 1.9.2 on Docker. It works well with PutHiveQL processor but always fails with PutHiveStreaming.

[image]

Comment: There is a similar article in the Cloudera community forum: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/NIFI-Can-t-connect-to-HiveMetastore-with-putHiveStreaming/td-p/221959. From what I read there, I suggest you test connectivity from your NiFi node to the Hive node port 9083. Does this help?

Comment: ...specifically, make sure you can connect to your Hive Metastore (`thrift://hive:9083`?) not your HiveServer2.

Comment: I can telnet to Hive metastore server and port from my NIFI node , and when I run ss -an | grep 9083 on  nifi node it's list all the process which connect to metastore host , and also i open the metastore logs and i find that nifi reach it and log get_table : db=databasename tbl=mytable, I can't find the problem

Answer (score 0):

The Hive components included with Apache NiFi are not compatible with
Hive 2.x, they are built with Hive 1.2.x. There is a Jira to add Hive
2 support ([NIFI-6456](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6456)) but it is not yet in NiFi.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply , but I just want to ask how puthiveql works with me even its   hive 2.x?

Comment: and sholud I go to NIFI-6456 and download this code and generate nar to access hive2 compenents?

Comment: You can try the code in the Jira case but it hasn't been fully tested or released, and it's been so long I don't even remember if it compiles at this point. Instead you might try the SIMBA driver for Hive and try the RDBMS components (like PutHiveQL). You won't be able to use Hive Streaming though, but PutDatabaseRecord might work.